# parsing a string looking at multiple delimiters

Tags: javascript, string, split

I am trying to parse a string into:

- Remove initial "lunch" word
- Split the rest into days of week and their associated food item

The input comes in just as a string in this format:

`var s = 'lunch monday: chicken and waffles, tuesday: mac and cheese, wednesday: salad';`

And my goal is to split into:

`[monday, chicken and waffles, tuesday, mac and cheese, wednesday, salad]`

I am using `s = s.split(' ').splice(1, s.length-1).join(' ').split(':');`

Which gets me:

`["monday", " chicken and waffles, tuesday", " mac and cheese, wednesday", " salad"]`

Obviously it's splitting on the `:` only, keeping the `,` there. I've tried using regex `split(":|\\,");` to split on `:` OR `,` but this does not work.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to split on both of those, you just need to adjust your Regular Expression a bit :

```
// Notice the 'g' flag which will match all instances of either character
input.split(/[:,]/g);
```

You could combine all of these to get what you are looking for via the[`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) functions:

```
// The initial replace will trim any leading "lunch " and the split will handle the rest
var output = input.replace(/^lunch /,'').split(/[:,]/g);
```

**Example**

```js
var input = 'lunch monday: chicken and waffles, tuesday: mac and cheese, wednesday: salad';
var output = input.replace(/^lunch /,'')
                  .split(/[:,]/g)
                  .filter(function(x){ return x.length > 0;});
alert(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if understand your goal. But is this

```js
 var string = 'lunch monday: chicken and waffles, tuesday: mac and cheese, wednesday: salad';

var splittedString = string.split(/:|,/);

splittedString.forEach(function(e){
    document.write(e + "<br>")
});
```

what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `replace()` and `split()`

```
var s = 'lunch monday: chicken and waffles, tuesday: mac and cheese, wednesday: salad';

s = s.replace('lunch ', '');
s = s.replace(/:(\ )/g, ',');
s = s.split(',');
console.log(s);
```

Output:

> > ["monday", "chicken and waffles", " tuesday", "mac and cheese", " wednesday", "salad"]